BNFの実装がうまくできない
実装したいBNFは下記です。
numbers ::= number | number numbers
number  ::= 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9

下記でやりたいことはできます。
int numbers(string& s, int& i)
{
    int n = s[i++] - '0';
    while(isdigit(s[i])) n = n*10 + s[i++] - '0';
    return n;
}

これを再帰を使って書きたいのですが、うまくいきません。
これだと１２はうまくいきますが、１２３は３３が返却されます。
ご教示いただけると幸いです。
int numbers(string& s, int& i)
{
　　int n = s[i++] - '0';
    
    if(isdigit(s[i]))
    {
        n = n*10 + numbers(s,i);
    }
    return n;
}


int n = s[i++] - '0';

で初期化したnを
n = n*10 + numbers(s,i);

の式では、1回しか10倍していないのが原因と思います。
＃質問の例「123」の場合、
n = 1 * 10 + 23 (=33)

となっているものと予想します。
抽出した「数字」(numbers)の桁数に比例して掛ける値を変更するようにすればよいと思います。
(質問文の場合、全部で3桁なので先頭桁の1は10*10倍)

問題が出ているコードでは最初の桁を100倍すべきところを10倍しかしてないですね。
int numbers(const std::string& s, int& i, int leading = 0) {
    int n = leading * 10 + (s[i++] - '0');
    return i < s.length() && std::isdigit(s[i]) ? numbers(s, i, n) : n;
}

ループで実装できるならループで良いと思います。再帰にしてもメリットはないでしょう。
BNFは文法の定義であって、実装の設計ではありません。
